# How to structure a referenced document that needs to be filtered on mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have an user document and a transactions document.

- The Transaction has a owner (User),
- The User has an set of Transactions that has no limit to grow.

I need to get the User transactions and filter it by some properties like, date range and paid or non paid.

As my transactions Schema is unbounded I used the mongoose virtuals to populate the User with the transactions, but as I see it's not possible to make MongoDb queries to a virtual because it's not really in the Data Base.

The use Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    ...
  },
);

userSchema.virtual('transactions', {
  ref: 'Transaction',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
});
```

The Transaction Schema:

```
const transactionSchema = new Schema({
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  ...
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I feel like I made some mistake on modeling the database this way. Which would be the best approach to this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use virtuals here. You have the user reference in your transaction model and it's enough. You can query whatever you like with mongo [aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
You can do the aggregation on transactions collection and use `$lookup` (as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)) to populate the users or query them.